# Any ideas on how to integrate a site with other open source software?

Tags: open-source, integration

Let say I have a site which want a OSQA , and a php BB with wordpress. All these thing have their implementation of login flow. Is there any share adapter to do the integration between that? Let say I only have one place to register and login, when I logged, the OSQA and php BB, and wordpress can automatically logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/). You can integrate bbPress with Wordpress' `wp_users` table by using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress-integration/) for bbPress.

OSQA doesn't seem so straight forward. However, people have had success integrating [OSQA with Drupal](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/9217/authenticating-osqa-from-drupal-site) so Wordpress integration should be possible, but doesn't seem to have been done yet.